# Magento 2.2 Order "Request does not match any route"

Tags: magento2, php

I've currently enabled purchase orders so that I can test offline payment methods (other primary method will be authorize.net direct post, but that's not currently enabled).

I've created 2 orders now, and every time I try to cancel or invoice either order I get an error on the page "Request does not match any route".  I don't seem to get any other error in the console.  I'm not seeing anything in any of the debug logs (and I'm in developer mode).  What can I do to debug this error to figure out why it's rejecting these changes?